# Angular ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'rating')

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm on a site where you can vote for an animal but I get an error when I select an animal. The error message is quite unclear to me, I've searched on google but I can't find a solution.

thank you.

**html**

```
<div class='wrapper'>
    <div class="cat" *ngFor="let cat of twoCatsArray" (click)="voteForThisCat(cat.id)">
        <img class="cat-image" [src]="cat.url">
    </div>
</div>
```

**ts.file**

```
  twoCatsArray: Cat[] = [];
  allcats: Cat[];

  constructor(private catService: CatService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.showMeTwoCats();
  }

  showMeTwoCats() {
    this.catService.getAllCat().subscribe((cats: CatList) => {
      this.allcats = cats.images;
      this.twoCatsArray = this.chooseTwoRandomCats(this.allcats);
    });
  }

  chooseTwoRandomCats(cats: Cat[]): Cat[] {
    const firstCatIndex = this.getRandomIndex(cats.length);
    const secondCatIndex = this.getRandomIndex(cats.length, firstCatIndex);

    return [cats[firstCatIndex], cats[secondCatIndex]];
  }

  getRandomIndex(maxValue: number, differentThanValue?: number): number {
    let index: number;
    do {
      index = this.getRandomInt(maxValue);
    } while (index === differentThanValue);
    return index;
  }

  getRandomInt(max: number): number {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(max));
  }

  voteForThisCat(id: string) {
    const likedCatindex = this.allcats.findIndex((cat: Cat) => cat.id === id);
    const newRating = this.getIncrementedCatRatingValue(this.twoCatsArray[likedCatindex].rating);
    this.twoCatsArray[likedCatindex].rating = newRating;

    this.twoCatsArray = this.chooseTwoRandomCats(this.allcats);
  }

  getIncrementedCatRatingValue(rating: number | undefined): number {
    return rating ? ++rating : 1;
  }
```

[image: screenshot of error]

Comment: What is `catVote`? Please provide sample data. While `this.catVote[likedCatindex].rating == newRating;`, double equal compare value but not assign value (`=`), are you sure is it correct?

Comment: no I'm not sure about that. I'm trying things out, I've updated my code, take a look at the catVote variable

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: ok fine I won't do it anymore

Answer (score 0):

There is a possible case you are trying to access the list **this.allcat**
when it's not loaded yet or your list doesn't contain the id.
Check the below snippet for better understand

```js
const list = [
    {id: 1, rating :1 },
    {id: 2, rating :2 },
    {id: 3, rating :3 },
    {id: 4, rating :4 },
];
const index = list.findIndex(i => i.id == 5);
console.log(index);
console.log(list[index]);
console.log(list[index].rating);
```

Comment: I've tried a few things that don't work, would you like me to post my entire ts file?